# Manipulate field from aggregate method

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I collect data off my database table. I'd like to manipulate one of the fields I'm getting back from the `aggregate()` method.

Currently, this is how I use `aggregate()` method:

```
const weeklyLogs = await Log.aggregate([
    { $match: { timestamp: { $gte: moment.tz('Asia/Jerusalem').subtract(6, 'days').startOf('day').toDate() } } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                $dateFromParts: {
                    year: { $year: { date: "$timestamp", timezone: "Asia/Jerusalem" } },
                    month: { $month: { date: "$timestamp", timezone: "Asia/Jerusalem" } },
                    day: { $dayOfMonth: { date: "$timestamp", timezone: "Asia/Jerusalem" } },
                    timezone: "Asia/Jerusalem"
                }
            },
            start: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [{ $eq: ['$eventName', 'connect'] }, 1, 0]
                }
            },
            end: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [{ $ne: ['$eventName', 'connect'] }, 1, 0]
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

This is how `timestamp` field (which is of type `Data`) looks in my DB (example): `2020-09-24T05:25:42.608+00:00`. So basically, When I get back the data from the method, it typically looks like:

```
end: 0
start: 9
_id: "2020-10-09T21:00:00.000Z"
```

But I'd like get back in the `_id` field the format of `dd/mm/yyyy` instead of `2020-10-09T21:00:00.000Z`. How could I manipulate it in the **`aggregate()` method**?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) utility:

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            $dateToString: {
                format: "%d/%m/%Y",
                date: "$timestamp"
            }
        },
        start: {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [{
                        $eq: ['$eventName', 'connect']
                    }, 1, 0]
            }
        },
        end: {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [{
                        $ne: ['$eventName', 'connect']
                    }, 1, 0]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And where do you place it?

Comment: Well, instead of `$dateFromParts` ;)